# fluent nhibernate many to many convention automapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am using FluentNH with automapping and conventions. I set up a Many-to-Many convention as such:

```
    public class HasManyToManyConvention : IHasManyToManyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IManyToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Key.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
            instance.Relationship.Column(instance.Relationship.StringIdentifierForModel + "Id");
        }
    }
```

Assuming these are my tables:
        User(Id,Username,Password), 
        Role(Id,Name)

Upon database generation, the associative table is being generated fine: 
        UserInRole(UserId,RoleId)

However, it has no composite primary key set. Any idea how to fix this from the convention?

Anyone? Might it be this is currently not supported by Fluent?

Comment: Each call to `instance.Relationship.Column()` adds another to the existing columns that are in the `instance.Relation.Columns` collection so that explains why you're getting a composite primary key set. I'm currently looking into a way of resetting the columns but so far I've been out of luck.

Comment: Please refer to my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772230/overriding-child-key-column-name-in-hasmanytomanyconvention

Comment: @SandorDrieënhuizen the referenced post has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the convention should remain the same. However, instead of using IList<User> and IList<Role> on my entity definitions, I'm now using ISet<User> and ISet<Role>. Now NHibernate will automatically create a composite primary key on the associative table.